# Partial specialization friend declaration

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In the following code:

```
template <typename U, typename V> class A {};
template <typename U, typename V> class B {};

template <typename T>
class C {
    template <typename U, typename V> friend class A;  // Works fine.
//  template <typename U> friend class B<U,T>;  // Won't compile.
};
```

I want `B<U,T>` to be friend to `C<T>`, that is, the second parameter of B must match C's parameter, though its first parameter can be anything.  How do I achieve this?  The friend declaration of `A<U,V>` is too much, though I will take that if I can't restrict it any further.

Perhaps define a meta-function

`template <typename, typename = void> struct FriendTraits { struct type{}; };`

or something like that within C?

The first 2 lines of

```
template <typename, typename = void> struct FriendTraits { struct type{}; };
template <typename U> struct FriendTraits<U,T> { using type = B<U,T> ; }  ;
template <typename U> friend typename FriendTraits<U,T>::type;
```

compiled, but not the important 3rd line (because it is the same problem).

Comment: You can't. This is banned by [temp.friend]/p8.

Comment: If true, then I have no choice but to declare the entire family friends then.  Excessive exposure, but there's no other choice really.

Comment: Very late, but I just wanted to mention that there could be a workaround to simulate friendship of partial specializations, if you can change the definition of `B`. [Here's some code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XSJHKvYZ9xuEYGyK). Maybe it will help in the future.