# Visual C++ error with friend template class in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, g++, clang++

I have a piece of code which works with g++/clang++. It has recently been reported to me that it breaks with Visual C++.

The code is this:

```
namespace q {
    template <typename X, typename Y>
    struct A {};
}

template <typename X>
struct B {
    template <typename Y>
    friend struct q::A;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

VC++ returns the following error:

```
source_file.cpp(9): error C2976: 'q::A': too few template arguments
source_file.cpp(3): note: see declaration of 'q::A'
source_file.cpp(10): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'B<X>' being compiled
```

Who is correct? Is there a portable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing template parameters properly should help:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
friend struct q::A;
```

Note that incorrectly declaring `A` as a friend makes program ill-formed, no diagnostic is required.

Comment: What I had hoped to achieve was to declare as friend only `q::A` where the `X` template parameter is the same as the enclosing `B` class. I now realize that what I wrote may not do what I intended, and that what I want may be a partial specialization, which is forbidden. Am I correct, or is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Svalorzen [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750755/partial-specialization-friend-declaration)